# Can we have a number system whose base value is r=0.

Tags: number-systems

Is it possible to have a number system with 0 as its base value? I haven't found any explanation as to why only numbers more than 1 is taken as a base value. For example, binary: base value is 2. decimal base value is 10.

Comment: How would you represent nonzero numbers in this system?

Comment: Using 0 and -1?

Comment: @Siamsiam But how do you represent -1? Or how do you even represent 1 for that matter?

Comment: "number system" and "base" are pretty flexible term.  What kind of "system" is the Roman Numeral system and it's base.  If you are considering numbers where an integer $x$ is written as $d_m....d_2d_1d_0$ when $x= d_m\times b^m + ... + d_2\times b^2 + d_1\times b + d_0$ and the $d_i $ belong to the finite set of digits, it should be obvious we can't have $b=0$ because then $b^m$ and $d_m\times b^m$ would always be $0$! and we'd have $x =d_0$ and there are only finitely many possible values of $d_0$.  (However.... it *is* possible to have $b$ but a *negative* value.)

Comment: How would that work of $x = a_m\times 0^m + a_{m-1}\times 0^{m-1} + .... + a_2\times 0^2 + a_1\times 0 + a_0 = a_0$?

Answer (score 1):

**Part** of the foundation of a number system (i.e. system of representing integers before and after the decimal point) of base $b$, where $~b \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ is that the following sequence is strictly increasing, and goes to infinity:

$$b^0, b^1, b^2, \cdots.$$

The above property does not apply to any integers $~< 2.$

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change the base of your number system, you're establishing the size / magnitude of a group, as well as how many distinct symbols are needed for all numbers to be written down. In base 2, numbers are grouped in 2's. every group of 2 creates a group who's size is 1 magnitude larger. the number 2 (in base 10) is two 1's (`1 + 1 = 10`) so it makes a single group of 2's. the only number's you use are 1 and 0.

In base 3, you have 0 1 and 2 available as symbols. `1+1+1 = 10`, because you now have a single group of 1's, where a group is defined as 3 units. `3 + 3 + 3` (base10) `= 10 + 10 + 10` (base3) `= 100` (base3)

If you are in base 0 however, you have no symbols to represent any numbers. You also can't group numbers into units because there are 0 units in a group

Comment: How about base 1?

Comment: base 1 has only 1 symbol that can be used. because of this, the number 0 is defined as an empty string, and every number is defined as that number of 1's. ```4``` (base10) ```=1111```(base1). ```6```(base10) ```= 111111``` base 1

Comment: But the base-1 (aka "unary") numeral system is very different from "normal" base-*n* systems, which have digits ranging from 0 to n-1, use O(log n) space to represent the integer *n* (as opposed to unary's O(n)), and can have "decimal point" notation using negative powers of the base to represent non-integers (which unary can't because negative powers of 1 are still just 1).  So it often makes sense to exclude unary from discussions of "base" notation.

Comment: I don't think it is usual to talk of 1 as the "base" of the [unary number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system) because unary is not a form of positional notation and has different properties: e.g., discarding the last digit corresponds to division by the base in a positional notation but to subtraction by $1$ in unary.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, when people refer to “Base-*b*” numerals, it means that:

- The concatenation of the digits $d_m...d_3d_2d_1d_0$ represents the number $\sum_{k=0}^m d_kb^k$.
- Numerals may optionally be extended by “decimal point” (more properly called “radix point” for $b \ne 10$) notation with $.d_{-1}d_{-2}d_{-3}...d_{-m} = \sum_{k=0}^m d_{-k}b^{-k}$ where the length $m$ may be either finite or infinite.  This allows integer bases to represent non-integer real numbers.
- As a consequence of $b^k$ in the above summations depending on the index $k$, numerals have “place value”, so digits cannot arbitrarily be re-ordered.  (For example, $24 \ne 42$.)
- Also, because the place value grows exponentially, representation of a number $n$ (if it doesn't require “decimal” places) uses $O(\log |n|)$ digits.
- Normally, each digit is an integer between $0$ and $b-1$.  However, this rule may be relaxed to accommodate negative, non-integer, or even complex bases.  It is also possible [to use negative-valued digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed-digit_representation) even with a positive base, with [balanced ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary) being the best-known of these systems.

It is *possible* to have $b = 1$; that's called [unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system).  But it differs from conventional Base-*b* numerals in several important ways:

- The “each digit is an integer between $0$ and $b-1$” rule is not followed, since having the sole digit be 0 would not allow representing any number other than 0.  So the digit is taken to have a value of 1 instead.
- Since $\forall k, 1^k = 1$, digits do not have place value.  All of the 1's in the unary numeral 1111 are just 1's, regardless of how many other 1's are after it.
- As a consequence of the above, radix point notation is useless, because all *negative* powers of 1 are also just 1, so can't be used to represent non-integers.  (You could, however, still use vulgar fraction notation like $\frac{1}{1111}$ for $\frac{1}{4}$.)
- The unary numeral for the integer *n* takes $O(n)$ space instead of $O(\log n)$.

Since unary is “special”, it's common to exclude it from discussions of number bases, or algorithms to convert between bases, and require $b \ge 2$.

Base-0, if it existed, would be even stranger than Base-1.  Place value is nonexistent, because $0^k = 0$.  Unless you rely on the definition $0^0 = 1$, in which case the one's place could have a nonzero value.  But since no *other* places could, it would be useless to have multi-digit numerals.  For *every* number to be one digit, every number would have to have its own unique symbol.  Obviously, it's unfeasible to define an infinite number of digits.  So Base-0 just can't work.